# Laravel : Call to a member function where() on float

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to find sum of different column using Query Builder.
Here is Query :

```
   DB::table('carts')                
           ->sum(\DB::raw('carts.price+COALESCE(carts.support,0)+COALESCE(carts.installation,0)' ))
           ->where('status','=',1)  
           ->where('user_id','=',$id);
```

But when i `dd()` the output i got the above Error.ie,

> Call to a member function where() on float

How do i avoid that?

Comment: please check your $id by dd($id) does it integer or not ?

Comment: `-$order->price = DB::table('carts')` is missing the full `->` is that a typo?

Comment: $id is OK ..it's a integer value @Sagar

Comment: that was typo sorry @DovBenyominSohacheski

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `sum` at the end of the query:

```
DB::table('carts')
   ->where('status', 1)  
   ->where('user_id', $id)
   ->sum(\DB::raw(
       'carts.price 
       + COALESCE(carts.support, 0) 
       + COALESCE(carts.installation, 0)' 
   ));
```

Answer (score 1):

[Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#Aggregates)

> The query builder also provides a variety of aggregate methods such as
>   `count`, `max`, `min`, `avg`, and `sum`. You may call any of these methods after
>   constructing your query:
>
> ```
> $users = DB::table('users')->count();
>
> $price = DB::table('orders')->max('price');
> ```
>
> Of course, you may combine these methods with other clauses:
>
> ```
> $price = DB::table('orders')
>                 ->where('finalized', 1)
>                 ->avg('price');
> ```